# How to fix this while loop so it breaks when it should?

Tags: python, while-loop

So when I answer with `l[0]` it doesn't break out from the y-loop but when I answer with `l[1]` it breaks out of the while loop. How can I make it so that both options breaks me out of the y-loop

```
while y == True:
  B=input("Klockan är 07:00 och du börjar snart, vad för slags frukost skulle du vilja
           ha? smörgås eller pannkakor: ")
  if B == l[0]:
    y=False
    b=True
    while b == True:
      D=input("utifrån det du har valt skulle jag villa rekommendera juice eller mjölk
               vad vill du ha?")
      if D == m[0]:
        print ("ok, ha en trevlig måltid")
        break
      if D == m[1]:
        print ("ok, ha en trevlig måltid")
        b=False
        break
        y=False
      else:
        b=True
        print ("Du har inte svarat på vilken drick du vill ha eller så har du använt
               stora bokstäver, var vänlig att svara igen")
  if B == l[1]:
    ö=True
    y=False
    while ö == True:
      D=input("utifrån det du har valt skulle jag villa rekommendera saft eller vatten
               vad vill du ha?")
      if D == m[2]:
        print ("ok, ha en trevlig måltid")
        ö=False
        break
        y=False
      if D == m[3]:
        print ("ok, ha en trevlig måltid")
        ö=False
        break
        y=False
      else:
        ö=True
        print ("Du har inte svarat på vilken drick du vill ha eller så har du använt
                stora bokstäver var vänlig svara igen
  else:
    y=True
    print ("Du har inte svarat på vilken rätt du vill ha eller så har du använt stora
            bokstäver, var vänlig att svara igen")
```

Comment: `y = False` after `break` doesn't do anything, because `break` immediately leaves the loop.

Comment: Change `if B  == l[1]:` to `elif B = l[1]:`

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you need to delete one line.
Your program after finishing `l[0]` the `l[1]` will be false so it will run the else `{}` and it will set y=true

I hope that makes sense.

```
else:

    y=True < ====== delete this
    print ("Du har inte svarat på vilken rätt du vill ha eller så har du använt stora 
            bokstäver, var vänlig att svara igen")`
```

Also you can fix your program by adding `else if B == l[1]:`  instead  of  `if B == l[1]:`